# Georeferencing using boundingbox coordinates for a Geotiff file that got converted from a JPEG

Tags: python, geospatial, gdal, rasterio

I'm currently working with aerial imagery that is only available as a JPEG. I got the data using a boundingbox with coordinate system EPSG:28992. Therefore, I thought I could georeference it with gdal using the coordinates of this boundingbox as Ground Control Points. However, the code works but when i open them with rasterio, the .tif files are still not georeferenced. Here is the code:

```
HRtif=gdal.Translate('orthoHR.tif', 'orthoHR.jpeg', format='GTiff' )
IRtif=gdal.Translate('ortho25IR.tif', 'ortho25IR.jpeg', format='GTiff' )


#georeferencing using bbox coordinates
HRref= gdal.Open('orthoHR.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
IRref= gdal.Open('ortho25IR.tif', gdal.GA_Update)

#set coordinate system
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(28992)

#GCPS bbox, p1=x1,y1 p2= x1,y2 p3= x2,y1 p4= x2,y2
x1=1633134.884
y1=3669075.728
x2=1652322.639
y2=3684544.511

gcp1= (x1, y1)
gcp2= (x1, y2) 
gcp3= (x2, y1) 
gcp4= (x2, y2)

#which pixels correspond
HRarray=HRref.ReadAsArray()
IRarray=IRref.ReadAsArray()
px1=0
py1=0
px2= HRarray.shape[1]
py2= HRarray.shape[2]

pp1= (px1, py1)
pp2= (px1, py2)
pp3= (px2, py1)
pp4= (px2, px2)

#make GCPS
gcps= [gdal.GCP(gcp1[0],gcp1[1], 0, pp1[0],pp1[1]),
       gdal.GCP(gcp2[0],gcp2[1], 0, pp2[0],pp2[1]),
       gdal.GCP(gcp3[0],gcp3[1], 0, pp3[0],pp3[1]),
       gdal.GCP(gcp4[0],gcp4[1], 0, pp4[0],pp4[1])]

#apply GCPS
HRref.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())
IRref.SetGCPs(gcps, sr.ExportToWkt())

HRref=None
IRref= None


HRras = rasterio.open('orthoHR.tif', driver='GTiff', crs='EPSG:28992')
IRras = rasterio.open('ortho25IR.tif', driver='GTiff', crs='EPSG:28992')



print(HRras.crs)
print(IRras.crs)
```

this is the output:

````
None
None
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rasterio/__init__.py:220: NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs. The identity matrix be returned.
  s = DatasetReader(path, driver=driver, sharing=sharing, **kwargs)```
````

Comment: Does `gdal.Info` correctly show the GCP's? Btw you can also add GCP's and the outputSRS directly when using `gdal.Translate`, see the `gdal.TranslateOptions`. But is it really necessary to use GCP's if the data is already in `EPSG:28992`, can't you simply set the geotransform & projection?

Comment: when i use dstSRS, it gives this error: 
TypeError: TranslateOptions() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dstSRS'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying a `crs` after opening with `rasterio` try setting the CRS of the original file before setting the GCPs:

just before

```py
#apply GCPS
HRref.SetSpatialRef(sr)
IRref.SetSpatialRef(sr)
HRref.SetGCPs(gcps, sr)
IRref.SetGCPs(gcps, sr)
```

Comment: When i try to do this i get this error:
` 67         return method(self)
     68     if (not static):
---> 69         return object.__getattr__(self, name)
     70     else:
     71         raise AttributeError(name)

AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Comment: On which line? `SetSpatialRef` or `SetGCP` ?

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to take a step back and start with where you got the data from. I'm not sure if it's a public service, but for example:
https://www.pdok.nl/introductie/-/article/luchtfoto-pdok

That shows for example the endpoint for the WMS infrared dataset:
https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=wms

You can run `gdalinfo` on the command line using that url to view the available layers/datasets in it. Unfortunately using `gdal.Info` from Python only shows "bands" which isn't helpful. But opening the main-url also allows retrieving the subdatasets like:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

wms_url = "https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?request=GetCapabilities&service=wms"

ds = gdal.OpenEx(wms_url)
sds = ds.GetSubDatasets()
ds = None
```

Now `sds` contains the subdatasets:

```py
[('WMS:https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=2016_ortho25IR&SRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=-2000.0,290000.0,294000.0,630000.0&TRANSPARENT=FALSE',
  'Luchtfoto 2016 Ortho 25cm Infrarood'),
 ('WMS:https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=2017_ortho25IR&SRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=-2000.0,290000.0,294000.0,630000.0&TRANSPARENT=FALSE',
  'Luchtfoto 2017 Ortho 25cm Infrarood'),
 ('WMS:https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=2018_ortho25IR&SRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=-2000.0,290000.0,294000.0,630000.0&TRANSPARENT=FALSE',
  'Luchtfoto 2018 Ortho 25cm Infrarood'),
 ('WMS:https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=2019_ortho25IR&SRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=-2000.0,290000.0,294000.0,630000.0&TRANSPARENT=FALSE',
  'Luchtfoto 2019 Ortho 25cm Infrarood'),
 ('WMS:https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=2020_ortho25IR&SRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=-2000.0,290000.0,294000.0,630000.0&TRANSPARENT=FALSE',
  'Luchtfoto 2020 Ortho 25cm Infrarood'),
 ('WMS:https://service.pdok.nl/hwh/luchtfotocir/wms/v1_0?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=Actueel_ortho25IR&SRS=EPSG:28992&BBOX=-2000.0,290000.0,294000.0,630000.0&TRANSPARENT=FALSE',
  'Luchtfoto Actueel Ortho 25cm Infrarood')]
```

If you explore the main url (`wms_url`), for example in the browser, you'll see that other projections are available, GDAL just selects/shows the first one. Which in this case also seems most reasonable.

The last entry in `sds` contains the latest imagery ("actueel") in this case. Using that to download a subset (at coarse 10m resolution) can for example be done with:

```py
wms_layer, layer_name = sds[-1]
output_tif = rf"C:\Temp\{layer_name.replace('' ', '_').lower}_10m_subset.tif"

ds = gdal.Translate(
    output_tif, 
    wms_layer, 
    projWin=[109000, 482000, 115000, 476000], 
    xRes=10,
    yRes=10
)
ds = None
```

That will download the data, and store it in an already georeferenced geotiff. Visualizing it in QGIS, superimposed on the "Google hybrid" layer from the QuickMapServices plugin looks like:

[image]

(Google maps certainly isn't perfectly georeferenced everywhere, so just use it as a quick check).

So if you've got your data in a similar way, it's probably already correctly georeferenced on the EPSG:28992 grid. In that case you should be able to simply assign the correct metadata. That would be preferred over georeferencing it using GCP's, which is usually only done for data which isn't yet correctly projected. The latter might potentially introduce inaccuracies, or trigger unnecessary resampling etc.

You can use gdal.Translate to convert the jpeg you have to a geotiff, assigning (not converting!) the projection/boundingbox can be done with something like:

```py
ds = gdal.Translate(out_tif, in_jpeg, outputBounds=bbox, outputSRS="EPSG:28992")
ds = None
```

Or a more manual way:

```py
ds = gdal.OpenEx(in_jpeg, gdal.GA_Update)

xsize = ds.RasterXSize
ysize = ds.RasterYSize

ds.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())

# convert boundingbox to geotransform
# gt = [ulx, xres, _, uly, _, yres]

ds.SetGeoTransform(gt)
ds = None
```